# Excel - checking for duplicates from a list of values within two columns of different groups of IDs

Tags: excel

I am trying to find a way to remove duplicates from a list of values between a column of "have and not have" and includes everything from the original list. I need this to repeat for each set of IDs.

This list would be: A1, B1, C1, D1, E1.

An example of the raw data would be:

```
UniqueID | Have | Not Have
---------------------------
Z12345   | A1   | B1
Z12345   | A1   | C1
Z12345   | A1   | D1
Z12345   | A1   | E1
Y12345   | A1   | D1
Y12345   | B1   | E1
Y12345   | C1   | D1
```

The output I'm trying to get is:

```
UniqueID | Have | Not Have
---------------------------
Z12345   | A1   | B1
Z12345   |      | C1
Z12345   |      | D1
Z12345   |      | E1
Y12345   | A1   | D1
Y12345   | B1   | E1
Y12345   | C1   |
```

I can't think of any way to approach this. I thought maybe running If statements to check if the IDs are matching and then run an if statement to remove the duplicates, but I couldn't figure out how to run it separately for each set of IDs. Any help or direction on how to approach this would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my attempt using formulas. I would consider this just a starting point to spark ideas or improve on. Basically I use the offset function to create a dynamic range for each UniqueID set. Can't guarantee that this totally works and with all the lookups I would imagine it might be really slow with a large data set.

I would not consider this robust as I made quite a few assumptions:

- Data is sorted by UniqueID
- There are no duplicates across columns
- The spreadsheet is setup exactly like this

  [image: setup]

First enter the following formulas:

```
D2: IF(A2<>A1,IFERROR(VALUE(D1),0)+COUNTA(A:A),D1)
E2: MATCH(B2,OFFSET($A$1,MATCH(A2,A:A,0)-1,1,COUNTIF(A:A,A2),1),0)+D2
F2: MATCH(C2,OFFSET($A$1,MATCH(A2,A:A,0)-1,2,COUNTIF(A:A,A2),1),0)+D2
G2: IF(E2>IFERROR(VALUE(E1),0),B2,"")
H2: IF(F2>IFERROR(VALUE(F1),0),C2,"")
```

Then copy these formulas down to the rest of the rows. Toggling formulas on (using ctrl+tilde) it should look like this:

[image: formulas1]

[image: formulas2]

[image: formulas3]

Results should look like this (columns G & H):

[image: results]

Comment: Thanks! Works with the example setup, and it kind of works with my data. I think I just need to mess with it a bit, but its definitely got me on the right track. Much appreciated :)

Comment: Sure, no problem. Would be interested to hear if you discover a more elegant way to do this. FYI, looks like I didn't list out the formulas correctly, but I assume you caught that if you were able to get this working. I've corrected it in case someone else comes across this.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a VBA routine to tackle this. It can be done with formulas (which I will post), but I believe it's more straightforward with VBA.

Assuming the list is sorted by UniqueID, you can trying the following code and modify as needed. To use it, first select the range of UniqueIDs before you run the macro. It will output the deduped values next to the original set.

```
Sub dedupe()
     Dim strList As String
    Dim strCurId As String
    Dim rng As Range   

    curId = Selection(1, 1)
    For Each rng In Selection
        If curId <> rng Then
            strList = ""
            curId = rng
        End If
        rng.Offset(0, 4) = rng
        If InStr(1, strList, rng.Offset(0, 1)) = 0 Then
            rng.Offset(0, 5) = rng.Offset(0, 1)
            strList = strList & "|" & rng.Offset(0, 1)
        End If
        If InStr(1, strList, rng.Offset(0, 2)) = 0 Then
            rng.Offset(0, 6) = rng.Offset(0, 2)
            strList = strList & "|" & rng.Offset(0, 2)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I had a feeling VBA would be a solution. Unfortunately, I don't really know how to use it yet, although it's definitely on my list of things to learn. What formula process would you use? Thanks in advance!!